# writing functions with control structures returns error

Tags: r

how come I keep getting system warning:

Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"

> }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

```
f <- function(a, b) {
if (a>b) { print(A wins) }
else { print(B wins) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need " " around what to print. so `print('A wins')` `print('B wins')` should work.